# AWS S3 Parallel Copy of Referenced Files

Tags: amazon-s3, parallel-processing

I recursively search a sub-directory for files that match specific criteria. I then output the filenames/paths to a flat file. I want to be able to copy the files that are referenced in that file to S3 in parallel mode to speed up the processing time. Example:

```
myfiles.txt:
/data/srv/prod1/file1.tar.gz
/data/srv/prod4/file12.tar.gz
/data/srv/prod2/file255.tar.gz
```

I can loop thru the file and perform the S3 Copy one-at-a-time but the files are very large and it takes a really long time.

**How can I copy the referenced files in parallel to S3?**

Answer (score 0):

When you loop through the file names you can start each transfer in its own process (or thread). By controlling the number of running processes or threads you can transfer multiple files at one time. However, transferring too many files at once could actually be detrimental to the speed of the transfers.

Answer (score 0):

Use GNU Parallel:

```
cat myfiles.txt |parallel -j0 s3cmd cp {} s3://bucket/folder/{/}
```

Adjust `-j0` until you find the max throughput.